# wxPython (Phoenix) retina status icon

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to built wxPython app for Mac OS X (El Capitan) and working on MBP with retina display.

I just copied Google Drive app status icons - 16x16 and 32x32 (2x) and get it blurry.

I also tried code from [this ticket](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15887) and it doesn't help.

My code looks like this:

```
icon = wx.Icon('icon@2x.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
```

And result (most left icon is mine):

[image]

wxPython version: 3.0.3.dev1836+f764b32 osx-cocoa (phoenix)

PS. I know that Google Drive built on wxPython too. but it have good retina images in status bar. How they do it?

Comment: Hmm. It looks like wx detecting my laptop as non-retina (wxOSXGetMainScreenContentScaleFactor is 1.0) for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check the scale before setting icon:

```
    import sys; print sys.version
    import wx; print wx.version()
    if 'phoenix' not in wx.PlatformInfo: exit()


    class CreateTestFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            return wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "test frame")


    wxSandbox = wx.App()

    testFrame = CreateTestFrame()
    print "Scale factor: ", testFrame.GetContentScaleFactor()

    if testFrame.GetContentScaleFactor() < 2.0:
        print "Not 'Retina' scaling"
        icon = wx.Icon('./icons/mac-normal.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        print "pixel height", icon.GetHeight()
    else:
        print "'Retina' scaling"
        icon = wx.Icon('./icons/mac-normal@2x.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        print "pixel height", icon.GetHeight()
    testFrame.SetIcon(icon)
    testFrame.Show()
    wxSandbox.MainLoop()
    exit()
```

The scale on my display is showing as '2.0' and it correctly selects the 32x32 icon.

> 2.7.11 (default, Dec  5 2015, 14:44:53)
>   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)]
>   '3.0.3(thorr18)-f764b32 osx-cocoa (phoenix)'
>   Scale factor:  2.0
>   'Retina' scaling
>   pixel height 32
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: It will not work see the my own comment (scale is detected as 1.0 at retina).

Comment: After it detects as 1.0, and selects the 16x16 icon, you get the blurry result?

Comment: It looks blurry for both 16x16/32x32 icons (tried without if condition).